# When do partial derivatives $p_x$, $p_y$ of a polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ not have any common factor?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

When do partial derivatives $p_x$, $p_y$ of a polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ not have any common factor? Is there a general approach for any number of variables, aka when is the variety defined by the partial derivatives vanishing (the would-be singular points) a finite point set? I.e. when in $\mathbb{C}[x, y, \dots]$ is changing the constant term not enough to render a variety nonsingular? Which means, when does $\mathbb{C}[x, y, \dots]^{\text{sing}}$, polynomials defining singular varieties, which we know is a Zariski closed subspace of generic codimension $\ge$ the number of variables $-\,2$, contain an affine hyperplane in $\mathbb{C}[x, y, \dots]$ which allows the constant to vary?

Comment: If $g^2$ divides $p$ then $g$ divides all partial derivatives of $p$. I am not sure if it is the only case, though.

Comment: I do not think this question has been answered. For example, in the two variable case, if we further assume that $p-a$ is irreducible for all $a\in\mathbb{C}$, then it is believed that $p=0$ is an affine line. A typical example where $p$ is not irreducible (other than what Felipe Voloch observes) is $p=x^2y-x$.

Comment: @Mohan Something is wrong with your example, as $p_x=2xy-1, p_y = x^2$ don't have a factor in common.

Comment: @Felipe Voloch, I am sorry, the first line of the question was to `study' examples where they do not have common factors. I hope I did not confuse everyone with my special example where they do not even have common zeroes. Apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of two variables, my example is the only one. Let $g$ be an irreducible polynomial that divides both $p_x,p_y$. On the curve $g=0$, we have $dp = p_xdx+p_ydy=0$ so $p$ is constant, say $p=c$ on this is curve, so $g$ divides $p-c$. Let's write $p-c = gh$ for some $h$. Then, again on $g=0$, $0=p_x = g_xh, 0=p_y=g_yh$. But $g_x,g_y$ cannot both vanish on $g=0$, so $h$ is divisible by $g$ and $p-c$ is divisible by $g^2$.